# Javascript/For Loop/Basic code/Only runs once

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

first off yes, I did look at many other codes on this topic and none of those are like mine. I have a very basic code so I apologize if I missed something obvious but I cannot understand why my code will only show one number.

Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test"></div>
<script>
var wildCard = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1);
var temp = 1;
for (var i=0; i < 5; i++){
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = wildCard + "<br />";
    temp++;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Very basic code, however the only thing is that I only get one random number printed instead of 5 going down in a vertical line. I would like to know what I am missing as to why it will not loop.

Comment: Every time you go through the loop you replace the entire contents of the DOM node, so you end up seeing only the last one (each iteration overwrites the previous one.)

Answer (score 1):

Reason why only one number gets printed instead of five is because the DOM node with id `test`'s inner html is replaced in every iteration. When the for-loop ends, you only see the value of the last iteration.

You can use `createTextNode` and `appendChild` to complete this task as follows:

```
var temp = 1;
for (var i=0; i < 5; i++){
    const wildCard = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1);
    const textNode = document.createTextNode(wildCard);
    const testDiv = document.getElementById("test");
    testDiv.appendChild(textNode)
    testDiv.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    temp++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate a new random number in each iteration of the loop, and then assign the full HTML once, after the loop has finished.

```
<script>  
    var temp = 1;
    var html = "";
    for (var i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        var wildCard = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1);
        html += wildCard + "<br/>";
        temp++;
    }
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = html;
</script>
```